# Save User Data to Firebase Database in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a registration activity for my app. I am using Kotlin und Firebase authentication. The registrazion itself already workds perfectly well (as well as the login acitivity).

My next goal is to save the user data (first of all the email) in the firebase database if the registration was successfull.

The function that I am using for that looks like that:

```
             fun writeNewUser(userId: String, email: String) {
                val user = User(email)

                database.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
            }
```

Here is the complete activity. There are no errors, my current problem is that the *writeNewUser* function is never used. Does anyone know why that could be?

```
package com.carlschwein.servus

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase


class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var etEmail: EditText
    lateinit var etConfPass: EditText
    private lateinit var etPass: EditText
    private lateinit var btnSignUp: Button
    lateinit var tvRedirectLogin: TextView

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.registration)

    // View Bindings
    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etSEmailAddress)
    etConfPass = findViewById(R.id.etSConfPassword)
    etPass = findViewById(R.id.etSPassword)
    btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSSigned)
    tvRedirectLogin = findViewById(R.id.tvRedirectLogin)
    database = Firebase.database.reference

    // Initialising auth object
    auth = Firebase.auth

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        signUpUser()
    }

    // switching from signUp Acitity to Login Activity
    tvRedirectLogin.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    }

}

private fun signUpUser() {
    val email = etEmail.text.toString()
    val pass = etPass.text.toString()
    val confirmPassword = etConfPass.text.toString()

    // check pass
    if (email.isBlank() || pass.isBlank() || confirmPassword.isBlank()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email und/oder Passwort dürfen nicht leer sein.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    if (pass != confirmPassword) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Die beiden Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
        return
    }
    // If all credential are correct
    // We call createUserWithEmailAndPassword
    // using auth object and pass the
    // email and pass in it.
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registrierung erfolgreich!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

             fun writeNewUser(userId: String, email: String) {
                val user = User(email)

                database.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
            }

            startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registrierung fehlgeschlagen. Daten bereits vorhanden oder fehlerhaft.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider [adding a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to `setValue`, so that you get notified if there's an error writing.

Comment: You are declaring a function definition (`fun writeNewUser`) inside your completion lambda (which is a bit odd), and then you never call that function anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the  `.setValue(user)` operation to see if something goes wrong? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

`fun writeNewUser(userId: String, email: String)` is not being called, you can move the function declaration outside of the completion listener attached to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` then call the function inside.

Like:

```
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registrierung erfolgreich!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

         >>>>>> HERE
        val uid = auth.currentUser.uid
        writeNewUser(uid, email)

        startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registrierung fehlgeschlagen. Daten bereits vorhanden oder fehlerhaft.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```